# Application hosting best approach

Tags: deployment, server, hosting

I'm finishing building my MERN stack web application and I started to think about the optimal way of deploying it.
What should be mentioned is that one of the features of the app is to allow the user to upload and modify a moderate amount of images. I know that two main approaches would be to either:

- host the app on a shared server like Namecheap and have the images stored in a filesystem
- host it using cloud-based PaaS solutions like Heroku with additional storage like Cloudinary.

My question is - which of those would be an optimal solution for an app that will serve mostly for academic purposes + as an addition to a portfolio? What would be the best approach if the goal would be to create the portfolio's website along with the project's one?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I would say the first option is probably cheaper if you have the disk space for it. You would also be under the hood more, connecting the filesystem to wherever your app is hosted. Depending on how many users you anticipate, the second option could scale and end up costing a bit.

Comment: Thank you for a fast response! To clarify a bit, I reckon that the second option could cost nothing if the app would really be only used by those with whom I'd share it, as it would only serve as part of portfolio + an academic task. The question is if it would actually be more cost efficient this way or rather by paying the $2.50 / month of the Namecheap server, and if adding additional websites like the one created for the personal portfolio would change the answer. My main problem is that I don't really know what I don't know, as I've never done it before.